# Error running Node.js app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, get, mozilla

I'm getting a frustrating "error" while trying to run a simple Node.js app on Heroku. Heroku itself is not reporting an error  - the app is up (not crashed, no "Hxx" codes being shown); what I get is this:

```
heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/index.html
host=realsheek.herokuapp.com fwd="24.63.82.165" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms
service=4ms status=404 bytes=33
```

When i run the app from the browser, it says `Cannot GET`. I don't know what it's trying to `GET`. My app is a test bed for a SocialProvider using Mozilla's SocialAPIs. The app itself is a version of the demo from `https://github.com/mixedpuppy/socialapi-demo`. A couple of bugs were fixed, else this is identical to this demo (i used the repo as is with just the bugs fixed). I have an `index.html` page which installs the SocialProvider, at which time the server-side app kicks in and does the rest of the magic. It runs fine on `localhost`, but when I push it up to Heroku, it fails. There were no problems reported with the `git push` (just the usual "no readme data" warnings).

I am stumped as I just can't see what it's trying to GET; obviously a 404 error suggests a missing page, but the app makes no calls to any `HTML` pages, and everything that's needed is present (as my run on `localhost` confirms).

I realize that this isn't a lot to go on, not seeing the actual app and not knowing what it's trying to do. And with no actual error to report - just a 404 status, it obviously could be anything. But I am stumped currently, so if anyone has any insight or suggestion, I'd be most grateful.

Comment: **Update:** I used a _LiveHTTPHeaders_ tool to inspect the headers and a GET is issued and nothing is returned (well, a 404 status).

I'm starting to suspect that the Heroku server setup is not like a conventional or popular Web server, where it's set up to deliver a `index.html` or `default.html` file in response to a GET with just the path. Instead, it feels like Heroku enables you to create whatever kind of server configuration you want, and does nothing "by default".

I'm thinking that the reason I get a 404 is I'm not actually returning anything - and it's my responsibility to do so.

Comment: **Update (cont'd)**: So in my `Node.js` app, as well as creating a server and listening to the outside, i also need to serve a static HTML page for the user to see.

If there's someone who knows Heroku and can confirm this, it will set me on the right track to develop the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Hi i too got frustrate  a lot while deploying the app.
in order to deploy you need to make sure about two things.

1) Set the port using environment variable `var port=Number(process.env.PORT || 3000);`

2) dont forget to include Procfile as web: node app.js(Your start file)

Comment: So you meant setting the port as a variable inside of app.js correct?

Answer (score 0):

That demo isn't a node app, or atleast isn't packaged the way heroku likes it with a Procfile and everything.  If you have a node app, then it would server the static files as per it's code (or atleast it should), but heroku isn't a standard web server for static pages (like Apache or nginx or whatever).  Heroku was built to run web apps, which are essentially their own servers.

If you get a node server running, this heroku quickstart for node should help you out.  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs

Comment: Thanks for replying, @Strat. I did go through that entire page while creating my app and have referred to it often. Your key point is that _"heroku isn't a standard web server for static pages (like Apache or nginx or whatever)._" This is the heart of the matter, and I am more and more convinced that my `index.html` isn't being loaded (and the initial browser `GET` fails) because I am not doing anything to serve that file, and Heroku won't do it for me out of the box; I need to create a basic server that responds to a `GET /` by loading the `index.html` and sending back. Then it should work.

Comment: I actually did take a look at the github you referenced, and app.js is a valid nodejs app that should serve static files - you just need a package.json file and Procfile (only need one line: node app.js) that will tell Heroku to build this package (since you are using libraries such as express) and launch app.js, which then you should be able to retrieve your static files like index.html.  The instructions for that should be on the heroku page as well.  Without that stuff, heroku has no idea what to do with the bulk of code you send it.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey @Strat - thank you again. Yep, I had both the `package.json` and `Procfile`s, and it was built fine. The problem was that the browser was issuing a `GET` but nothing in the app was serving the page. Once I added a `app.use(express.static(__dirname)...)`, all was well - a page was being served, the 404 went away, and the app worked. So thanks for taking the time to reply - as you see, you were the only one. Cheers....

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The solution was as simple as:

1) Make sure to have a Procfile correctly written. It should look like:

```
web: node index.js
```

2) After pushing the code to heroku, try to run the following command:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have a express js app where my Procfile says web: node app.js , do i need to change it to index.js? does that mean I need to transfer my app.js code to index.js or does the app.js remain as it is?